# WordPress MySQL Database goes up and down

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, digital-ocean

hopefully a simple question.

I have a WordPress droplet installed on DigitalOcean. I had to go into the Database to change a username and password via command tools, and the guide I followed had me do the following steps:

```
    Access mysql as root:

mysql -u root

    List your databases:

show databases;

    Select your database:

use yourdatabasename;

    List the database tables:

show tables;
```

Now what happened was when I used the uh use command, that seemed to have made my WordPress lose a establishing connection with my Database for more than about twenty seconds. The site will work, but then go down.

Is there anyway to fix this or am I boned? If I run "show databases" again, I get the following:

```
information_schema
mysql
performance_schema
sys
wordpress
```

Thank you so much for any help!

Edit: Just some more context, this is a barebones WordPress installation with just the following plugins:

ACF
WooCommerce
Ninja Forms

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured this out! All I needed was a swapfile made.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-space-on-ubuntu-18-04